# É realmente necessário excluir underlines das postagens?

Tags: suporte, formatação, markdown

Recentemente ao responder um comentário sobre PHP, os underlines da minha resposta foram ocultados, logo se tratavam de constantes mágicas, métodos que necessitam de 4 underlines, não tenho conhecimento se nas perguntas os mesmos são ocultados também.

> **DIR**

agora já sei...

enfim, isso é realmente necessário? há algum tipo de ameaça de injeção nisso?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eles não foram ocultados, isso faz parte da formatação usada no site ([vide markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). Qualquer texto entre dois *underscores* (ou asteriscos) são tratados como **negrito**.

Isso me parece ser parte do código, então deveria estar na formação de código. Os blocos de código não têm formatação como o resto do texto

Ex.:

`__DIR__` ou

```
__DIR__
```

Também é possível escapar estes caracteres usando barras invertidas (`\`), veja:

O texto `\_\_DIR\_\_` fica  __DIR__